# Any open source Twitter library that handles authentication and twitter posts for ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implement two pieces of functionality to my ASP.NET MVC 3 applications.

1. I would like the ability for the user to use Twitter to authenticate on my web site. I would also like to be able to store the users name and email in my database upon successful login.
2. I would like to post to the users twitter feed once a certain event occurs.

Are there any open source libraries that can handle both tasks out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable logging in with Twitter credentials on your site, use the [Sign in with Twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter) flow. If the user is already authenticated, it's a one click operation.  The doc I linked has a flowchart and description of the process, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233815/twitter-api-authorization-of-my-application/6234528#6234528) has a bit more detail.

Once your user has signed in via Twitter, you can easily get the user's `screen_name`, however there is no facility to obtain the user's email from Twitter.

On the Twitter framework front, I recommend [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/).  I like the consistency and ease-of-use of the framework, and coverage of- and parity with- the Twitter APIs.  I've personally used it on multiple implementations, and have had no issues that tied back directly to the library.

In order to use Sign in with Twitter, you'll need to use the [`BuildAuthorizationUri(string requestToken, bool authenticate)`](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/html/M_Twitterizer_OAuthUtility_BuildAuthorizationUri_1.htm) method overload of the `OAuthUtility` class, passing `true` as the second parameter.

Also, [Ricky Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157830/ricky-smith) (the Twitterizer lead dev) is active on SO, and anything tagged with **twitterizer** seems to get pretty prompt attention (meaning I can't answer them faster than Ricky can. ;)

Finally, posting a status to a user's timeline is pretty trivial with Twitterizer once the OAuth tokens have been obtained (simplified example from the Twitterizer site follows):

```cs
var tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.AccessToken = "XXX";
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "XXX";
tokens.ConsumerKey = "XXX";
tokens.ConsumerSecret = "XXX";

TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "Hello, #Twitterizer");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think that either of the following would be able to handle both your tasks:

- [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/)
- [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org)

Answer (score 0):

Also consider...

[Twitterizer](http://twitterizer.net)
 or 
[TwitterVB](http://twittervb.codeplex.com)