# PHP Oauth Client (1.0a & 2.0): App Keeps Asking Authorization

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, yahoo-api

I am new to Oauth implementation and has been searching the web for libraries that I could use and I have found [Manuel Lemos' Oauth Client](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html).

Anyway, the problem that I have right now is about re-authorization everytime session expires.

I would like to implement Oauth with my project using facebook, twitter, yahoo and google.

I have managed to get it working but I think I am lost in some point after the access token is obtained and the app has been authorized by the user.

I encounter this issue with **yahoo**, **twitter** and **google** (except Facebook) wherein when the access token (or the session) expires and using these "Severs" again it always redirects back to the authorization page and asks for the user to authorize the app (again).

What should I do so that yahoo, twitter and google will only authorize once (except on revoked permissions) and when the user returns and use it again it will automatically obtain the user data without asking authorization again?

here's a part of the code that performs the request:

```
            if( ( $success = $client->Initialize() ) ) 
            {   

                if( ( $success = $client->Process() ) ) 
                {       

                    if( strlen( $client->access_token ) ) 
                    { 

                        $success = $client->CallAPI( 
                            $apiurl
                            , 'GET'
                            , $apiqry
                            , array( 'FailOnAccessError'=>true )
                            , $user);


                    }

                    elseif(strlen($client->authorization_error))
                    {
                        $client->error = $client->authorization_error;
                        $success = false;
                    }

                }

                $success = $client->Finalize($success);

            }
```

I have tried the following solutions but no luck :(

[Twitter OAuth - checking if access to application is granted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685903/twitter-oauth-checking-if-access-to-application-is-granted)

[Twitter - Already have OAuth database, how do I know who the user is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492224/twitter-already-have-oauth-database-how-do-i-know-who-the-user-is)

[Twitter api authorization of my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233815/twitter-api-authorization-of-my-application)

and a bunch of others but none of them worked..

Thank you!